# Is there a way to make the first digit of int always start with 1 in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have the following class constructor:

```
class Car(val brand: Brand,val modelName: String, val version: Int){}
```

If for example, I want the version number to always start with 1. Is there a way to manipulate it in the class body to achieve this ?

Meaning:

```
val firstdigit:Int = abs(version).ToString().Substring(0,1)
```

And then parse it to Int. But how to replace the original first digit after that?
I'm just learning Kotlin and I got a bit stuck with this

Comment: It's not really clear what you want here. Your code seems to imply `-123` is a valid version. Is that the case?  What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure you actually want an `Int` for the `version` instead of a `String` or some other type?

Comment: Yes, version must be a numeric type. No, negative values are not accepted. I just need the version property which must be a number to always start with 1, and then it just gets incremented each time a new Car class instance is called. I'm not sure if that makes it clearer

Comment: This doesn't explain _how_ you want to transform numbers that don't start with a 1. Do you want to _replace_ the first digit if it's not 1 (e.g. 0→1, 2→1, 9→1, 20→10, 21→11, 321→121)? Or _prepend_ a 1 (e.g. 0→1, 2→12, 9→19, 20→120, 321→1321)? Or _round_ up to the nearest power of 10 (e.g. 0→1, 2→10, 9→10, 20→100, 321→1000)?

Comment: Do you want to enforce a validation, and ensure that when *any* `Car` is instantiated the `version` *must* start with `1`? Or do you want to always prepend `1` to any given `version` (even if it already starts with `1`)? So you can create an instance `Car("brand", "name", 23)` and then `car.version` returns `123`?

Comment: I think validation would make more sense, although I think it would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already said in the comments that you want the number to increment per instance, so the caller shouldn't be providing that number in the first place really! But just generally, here's two approaches to sanitising your input parameters:

*1) Make it the caller's responsibility to provide valid data*

```
init {
    require(version.toString().first() == '1') { "Needs to start with 1 thanks" }
}
```

`require` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if it fails, which is the standard exception for "the value of this argument is invalid". Should the class be responsible for taking bad data and trying to "fix" it, or should the caller be handling that - and maybe not constructing an instance at all if it doesn't have valid data?

*2. create a `newInstance` function that uses valid data, and keep the constructor private*

```
class Thing private constructor(val number: Int){
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(num: Int): Thing {
            return Thing(abs(num))
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    Thing.newInstance(-2).let { println(it.number)}
}
```

If it makes sense for the class itself to sanitise the input parameters, you can delegate construction to a function that takes care of that, and prevent things from calling the constructor directly with potentially bad data.

This can cause issues with e.g. serialisation libraries (which want to call the constructor directly) but in that case you could leave the constructor public, and just *advise* callers to call `newInstance` instead. Not ideal, but it's an option!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

```kotlin
class Car(val brand: Brand, val modelName: String) {
    val version = getNextVersion()
    
    companion object {
        private var nextVersion = 0
        
        private fun getNextVersion(): Int {
            nextVersion++
            if (nextVersion.toString()[0] != '1') {
                nextVersion = (10.0.pow(ceil(log10(nextVersion.toDouble())))).toInt()
            }
            return nextVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if the version number is meant to increment for each new instance of `Car`, then the caller shouldn't have any influence on what that number is, so it shouldn't be a parameter. (You also might want to make `getNextVersion()` `synchronized` so it's thread-safe and updates atomically)

Comment: I think this should work. Can you please explain why we need a companion object in this case?

Comment: Without it, there is no central authority for what the current/next version is. It doesn't have to be in the companion object per se, it can be anywhere so long as it's a "single source of truth" (e.g. top level function, separate `VersionHelper` class, etc.)

Comment: Basically, just what @cactustictacs said: "the caller shouldn't have any influence on what that number is, so it shouldn't be a parameter"